# D3 Changing the Attribute of an Individual Node

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have two d3 visualizations, and when I click on a link on the sankey diagram (defined by an email), I want to change the radius of the corresponding node (with the same email) on the force directed network graph. No matter what I try or search on the internet I cannot find a way to adjust the attribute of one individual node without selecting all the circles.

[image: Picture of Visualizations]

```
var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .on("click", function (d,i){
      svg2.selectAll("circle").each(function (f,i){
          if (f.id == d.email)
          {
              //CHANGE RADIUS OF F or color or anything
              //svg2.select(f).attr("r",10); DOESNT WORK
              //f.attr("r",10) DOESNT WORK
          }
      });
      
  })
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) 
  { return Math.max(0.2, d.dy); })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });
```

Comment: It appears that you are treating the datum (`f`) as the node (`this`) - you cannot select the datum, try `d3.select(this).attr("r")` inside your if block.